# How do we revive an unprotected li ion 18650 battery

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, repair

How can we confidently revive and recondition an unprotected li ion 18650 battery by aid of common electronic tools and kits

Comment: Be sure you know what you are doing, a mistake can cause a fire and hurt you. Even though the flame is great to look at it is deadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

When a LiPo batteries voltage drops below a certain point, the lithium begins to precipitate and creates tiny sharp needles of metal.   These needles don't dissolve upon recharging.  Instead, they remain, and eventually may poke through the plastic separator causing an internal short.  Then you get to watch the fireworks.

Plenty people talk about reconditioning or recharging over discharged LiPo.   Yes it usually works.  It is not safe.   You asked how to do it "confidently".  A cell that you can not know is safe you cannot be 'confident' in.